# socat fake http server - use a file as server response

Tags: socat

I've been trying to use socat to respond on each connection to a socket it's listening to with a fake HTTP reply. I cannot get it working. It might be because I'm using the cygwin version of socat? I don't know.

Part of the problem is I want the second argument `<some_file_response>` not to be written to. In other words because it's bidirectional it will read what's in response.txt and then write to that same file, and I don't want that. Even if I do `open:response.txt,rdonly` it doesn't work repeatedly. `system:` doesn't seem to do anything. `exec` seems like it works, for example I can do `exec:'cat response.txt'` but that never gets sent to the client connecting to port 1234.

```
socat -vv tcp-listen:1234,reuseaddr,fork <some_file_response>
```

*I want it to read a file to the client that's connected and then close the connection, and do that over and over again (that's why I used fork).*

**I am putting a bounty on this question. Please only give me solutions that work with the cygwin version from the windows command prompt.**

Answer (score 15):

Tested with cygwin:

```
socat -v -v TCP-LISTEN:1234,crlf,reuseaddr,fork SYSTEM:"echo HTTP/1.0 200; echo Content-Type\: text/plain; echo; cat <some_file_response>"
```

If you do not want a complete HTTP response, leave out the echos:

```
socat -v -v TCP-LISTEN:1234,crlf,reuseaddr,fork SYSTEM:"cat <some_file_response>"
```

Comment: `-v -v` in Ubuntu

Answer (score 5):

Taken from socat [examples](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/machine/penguin-lust/src/socat-1.7.1.2/EXAMPLES)

```
socat -vv TCP-LISTEN:8000,crlf,reuseaddr,fork SYSTEM:"echo HTTP/1.0 200; echo Content-Type\: text/plain; echo; cat"
```

Comment: This command just echoes back what the client types. (Just as hinted in the examples: "a very primitive HTTP/1.0 echo server").

Answer (score 2):

This one works:

```
socat -v -v -d -d TCP-LISTEN:8080,reuseaddr,fork exec:"cat http.response",pipes
```

Two things need to be aware,

- should you add `crlf`, as in other answers. I recommend not.

  1. [crlf caused problem sending image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351097/send-image-over-http-via-socat-bash-webserver)
  2. just use \r\n explicitly in http response headers.
- without `pipes`, seems no data sent to client. browser complains:

  *127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data.
  ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE*

tested in cygwin.

**== EDIT ==**

If you want use inside `cmd.exe`, make sure PATH is correctly set, so that `socat` and `cat` can be found.

Say both `socat.exe` and `cat.exe` located under `E:\cygwin64\bin`

```
set PATH=%PATH%;E:\cygwin64\bin
```

Works in `cmd.exe`, with `socat` & `cat` from cygwin.